# i have a 220v well pump is it ac or dc that i should set my tester on when it goes out

Tags: electrical

I have a 220 well pump that has stopped working .  I bought a digital multi tester to check it but I don't know if I need to check ac or DC

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It isn't clear what you'd be testing, but a) the pump is almost certainly AC, and b) it isn't clear you know enough to test the system without getting yourself hurt.

Answer (score 1):

220v to a well pump is AC. Such a high voltage delivered to a home would never be DC. In fact, DC of any voltage, except low voltage lighting for example, in a home would be rare; maybe unheard of.

Comment: Well there are DC pumps but not on a standard well , as my high school teacher said we can never use never or always !

Comment: @EdBeal Are there 220V DC pumps that you would find use for in a home?

Comment: Well, by golly @EdBeal , I don't seem to be able to even find such a thing as a 220v DC well pump of any kind.

Comment: There are DC well pumps (think solar)  and as far as DC and high voltage I work on a 60 HP 460v motor and most of the smaller servo drives are 90+ vdc.

Comment: @EdBeal Is that 460V one DC? I haven't been able to find one online higher than 48 volts DC.

Comment: yes I just replaced the 4 x 4 shunt brushes in it last week. The biggest DC motor I have worked on lately is 350HP and the largest one I ever worked on was 500hp. DC has very good low speed torque (ac not so good at low speed). With gear boxes and VFD's AC has become the standard for most applications but not all.

Comment: You wouldn't want 220V DC.   I work in high-voltage DC a lot.  It requires very special handling, because it loves to arc, and with no zero crossings, nothing extinguishes the arc.  Even a simple thing like a switch is a lot more complicated. Most of the switching gear I deal with has an 8-10x voltage derate when used on DC, so your house would need gear appropriate for 2200VAC.